# How to solve differential equation with dx and dy in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, differential-equations, calculus

I am trying to solve the equation: (3xy^2)dx + (2x^2y)dy = 0 in matlab but I can't get it to work. Can you please help me? This is my code so far.

The dx and dy do not show up in matlab, as ML thinks they are 1. Then dsolve returns an error.

This is my code:

```
syms dy dx y x

dy = diff(y)
dx = diff(x)

eqn = 3*x*y^2*dx + 2*x^2*y*dy == 0

dsolve(eqn)
```

I tried to use dsolve.

Edit: the answer is C = (x^3y^2)^(1/5)

Comment: please [edit] the question to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code and include the full error message you're seeing

Comment: Are `dx` and `dy` supposed to represent the time derivatives of `x` and `y` by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dx` and `dy` actually represent the derivatives of `x` and `y` with respect to an independent variable such as time, you need to define your derivatives with respect to this independent variable upon which out depends. This can be dune using an [abstract symbolic function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html):

```
syms x(t) y(t);
```

Then [`sym/diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html) will implicitly understand what to differentiate with respect to:

```
dx = diff(x); % equivalent to diff(x(t), t)
dy = diff(y); % equivalent to diff(y(t), t)
```

Finally, you can use your original differential equation with [`dsolve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html) as before:

```
eqn = 3*x*y^2*dx + 2*x^2*y*dy == 0;
dsolve(eqn)
```

This returns two solutions, `0` and `C1/x(t)^(3/2)` (the constant `C1` is because you have not defined any initial conditions).

On the other hand, if `y` is actually a function of the independent variable `x` instead of time you'll need to do something akin to what @duffymo suggested:

```
syms y(x);
dydx = diff(y);
eqn = 3*x*y^2 + 2*x^2*y*dydx == 0;
dsolve(eqn)
```

Comment: Should be the second one.  My understanding of calculus would view x as the independent variable and y as dependent on x.  No need to introduce a new variable t.

Comment: How do I make sure that there is a y in the solution? The answer is C = (x^3y^2)^(1/5)

Comment: Of course there is.  I see a y there.  Don't you?  You can use algebra to solve for y in terms of x.  Raise both sides to the 5th power and get started.  y(x) = sqrt(C^5/x^3)

Comment: @duffymo I’m not assuming that the original equation was correctly captured – that why I asked for clarification from the OP

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange it to look like this:

```
y' = 3xy^2/2x^2y
```

This is a separable, non-linear, first-order ordinary differential equation.

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27+%3D+3xy%5E2%2F2x%5E2y) is the solution from Wolfram Alpha.